# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{(-t*x)}\frac{(cos(x)-1)}{x} dx$

Tags: derivatives, improper-integrals, self-learning, trigonometric-integrals

I want to prove $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-t*x}\frac{\cos{(x)}-1)}{x}dx=\ln{\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}$ for $t>0$.

What happens to this integral as $t\rightarrow 0^+?$

My attempt:-

Let $F(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} \frac{(\cos{(x)}-1)}{x}dx$

If we compute $F'(t)$ for $t>0$ using differentiation under integral sign,we get,

$$F'(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{-tx}\frac{\cos{(x)}-1}{x}\right)dx=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty-e^{-tx}(\cos{(x)}-1)dx$$

and

$$F''(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x*e^{-tx}(\cos{(x)}-1)dx$$

Now , how to utilise these results to answer the question?

Comment: $F'(t) $ is easy enough to be evaluated.  Just use integration by parts

Comment: @Azlif, I got the answer to this question.